# Generating Categories and Subcategories in my RazorPage form

Tags: asp.net-core, categories, razor-pages, selectlistitem

I try to make a form with category and subcategory which are all checkbox and use it to set my service categories and subcategories. I try some method like using SelectListItem but I couldn't use it for indented checkbox. 
this is my database diagram (I know it's not good, but the customer wanted it) :
[Services Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6vXx.png)

My method to make a List of SelectListItem for Main and Sub categories:

```cs
public List<SelectListItem> GetAllMajorCategories()
    {
        return _context.CategoriesTbl
            .Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
                Text = c.Title
            }).ToList();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetAllSubCategories()
    {
        return _context.CategoriesTbl
            .Where(c => c.ParentId == c.CategoryId)
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.ParentId.ToString(),
                Text = c.Title
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Then I use these two method in my PageModel:

```cs
public void OnGet()
    {
        MainCategories = _serviceServices.GetAllMajorCategories();
        SubCategories = _serviceServices.GetAllSubCategories();
    }
```

Then in the Razorview I want to generate checkbox for every MajorCategory and it's SubCategories but I can't.

```cs
    <div class="form-group">
@foreach (var item in Model.MainCategories)
    {
        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue">
        <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="majorCat" name="majorCat" value="@item.Value">
        <label> @item.Text </label>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: By testing your code, your view can generate checkboxes of MajorCategory . The same method can operate on SubCategories . Can you describe in detail where your errors are?

Comment: There is no error, I just wanna generate subcategories nested below each major categories.

Comment: the GetAllSubCategories() I think return wrong list, I can't use it for generating subcategories depend on it's majorcategory . that's where I got stock. if you have a better solution to do the same thing, it will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to your comment , the GetAllSubCategories() method did
>   return the wrong list，you just need to retutn CategoriesTbl's list
>   when ParentId is not null.

Please refer to the following code for details：

PageModel.cs

```
 public void OnGet()
    {
        MainCategories = GetAllMajorCategories();
        SubCategories = GetAllSubCategories();
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> GetAllMajorCategories()
    {
        return _context.CategoriesTbl
     .Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
     .Select(c => new SelectListItem
     {
         Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
         Text = c.Title
     }).ToList();
    }

    public List<CategoriesTbl> GetAllSubCategories()
    {
        return _context.CategoriesTbl.Where(c => c.ParentId != null).ToList();
    }
```

View:

```html
@page
@model WebApplication1_rzaor_page.ShowCheckboxModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowCheckbox";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>ShowCheckbox</h1>

<div class="form-group"> 
    @foreach (var item in Model.MainCategories)
    {
        <div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue">
            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="majorCat" name="majorCat" value="@item.Value">
            <label>@item.Text</label>
        </div>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var subitem in Model.SubCategories.Where(x => x.ParentId == Convert.ToInt32(item.Value)).ToArray())
            {
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="subCat" name="subCat" value="@subitem.CategoryId">
                    <label>@subitem.Title</label>
                </li>
            }

        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Comment: WOW, That was great. it worked. Thank you so much. Now I have to use it again for Edit my services which I think is another challenge for me.